# Remove html tags from an image's ALT tag

Tags: php

May I remove all HTML tags from an image's alt tag?

String below is output of a PHP function :-

```
    The program makes it very easy to visualize a function and paste it into another program. It is also possible to do some mathematical calculations on the functions.

    <img src="https://domainname.com/media/heat-resistant-graph.png" alt="Heat Resistance of <a class='bluetext showgeorge' href='/definition/FKM' data-id='28'>FKM</a>" >
```

I would like to remove all HTML tags from ALT. My code below -

```
   $alt_tags = preg_match('/alt=".*."/', $page_content, $match); 
   foreach ($match as $tag ){
   $page_content = str_replace($tag, strip_tags($tag), $page_content);
   }
   echo htmlspecialchars_decode(nl2br($page_content));
```

However, strip_tags($tag) outputs alt="Heat Resistance of FKM">

I am unsure why I am getting > at the end. Can anyone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5de8bb952dcee12c413269d2dc7047d763a155e i could not reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems:

1- Take care of your quotation marks in alt tag. 
You have: `alt=".....'`. ! Notice you do not have same opening and closing quotations.

2- `<a href=".." />` is another element, which means you cannot add it inside a tag.

And always remember:

> Always open & close tags, quotation marks etc immediately, or else you will forget to close them.

Comment: His alt tag is fully enclosed with double quotes. The inner html in the alt tag has single quotes. The whole question is how to strip the inner html out. You have solved nothing with this comment.